# SQL : ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql

The thing is that it does return one row.

Here's the thing.

```
SELECT...

FROM...

WHERE...

GROUP BY...

HAVING randomNumber > (SELECT value FROM.....)
```

Whenever I have signs such as =, >  it always returns me this error. When I do IN it doesn't.

Are you not supposed to use comparison signs when comparing to another table?

Comment: IN expects 1 or more values returned from subselect. Comparison operators expect only a single return value. Your problem is that you're using comparison on multiple results from subselect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type:

```
SomeValue IN (SELECT ...)
```

it is equivalent to using:

```
SomeValue = ANY (SELECT ...)
```

Don't use the second notation - but it illustrates a point.  When the SELECT returns more than one value, you must use ANY or ALL with the comparator.  When you omit ANY or ALL, then you must have a SELECT that returns exactly one value.

Comment: Why do you recommend not using 'SomeValue = ANY (SELECT ...) '?

Comment: Because the familiar spelling is `SomeValue IN (SELECT …)`.  People (think they) know what that means without looking it up; they probably have to think hard to come to the same conclusion if you use `= ANY`.   The negated versions are harder still: `!= ANY` and `!= ALL` are a real pain to sort through.

Comment: It was surprisingly hard to find someone on SO mentioning `IN` instead of `=` to avoid this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple values with `IN` operator. If you are using `>, = , <` etc. try using this:

```
HAVING randomNUmber > (SELECT MAX(value) FROM ......)
```