# Simple SQL returns "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I researched these links:

[More than one row returned by a subquery in simple SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713338/more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-in-simple-sql)

[SQL : ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848679/sql-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression)

[DatabaseError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression (Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853725/databaseerror-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression-d)

[ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900774/error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression)

[`single-row subquery returns more than one row` error unclarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681545/single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row-error-unclarity)

...however they appear to be using filtering of various kinds within their queries, or they have sub-selects with multiple rows returned when one row is expected.  My query is simpler, and should NOT expect only one row to be returned (from what I can tell).  I simply want to select all from a view using postgresql-9.1:

```
# select * from MYVIEW;
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

whereas this works:
    `# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYVIEW;
     count 
    -------
         5
    (1 row)`

here is the general definition of my view (NOTE that the below is only provided for reference to what I'm selecting from, it is not what is receiving the error.  The error is only received when running the 'select all' posted above):

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEW(ID1, ID2, ID3, KEY1, KEY2, ID4, TXT1, ID5, LOC1) AS 
SELECT 
    TABLE1.ID1, 
    (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE3.TABLE3_ID = TABLE2.TABLE3_ID AND NAME = 'blah1' ) as ID2,
    (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE3.TABLE3_ID = TABLE2.TABLE3_ID AND NAME = 'blah2' ) as ID3,
    (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE3.TABLE3_ID = TABLE2.TABLE3_ID AND NAME = 'blah3') as KEY1,
    (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE3.TABLE3_ID = TABLE2.TABLE3_ID AND NAME = 'blah4') as KEY2, 
    TABLE4.ID6,
    TABLE4.NAME,
    ID5,
    coalesce(
        (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE5 WHERE TABLE5.ID5 = TABLE6.ID5 AND NAME = 'BLAH5'), 
        (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE7 WHERE TABLE7.ID6 = TABLE6.ID6 AND NAME = 'BLAH5' )
    ) as LOC1 
FROM TABLE3, TABLE6, TABLE1, TABLE4, TABLE8 
WHERE 
    TABLE3.TABLE8_ID = TABLE8.TABLE8_ID AND 
    TABLE3.ID1 = TABLE1.ID1 AND 
    TABLE8.TABLE8_ID = TABLE4.TABLE8_ID AND 
    TABLE4.ID6 = TABLE6.ID6 AND 
    TABLE6.TABLE3_ID = TABLE3.TABLE3_ID and 
    TABLE8.NAME = 'BLAH6' and 
    TABLE8.on = true and 
    TABLE4.ON = true and 
    TABLE6.ON = true and 
    TABLE1.ON = true AND 
    TABLE3.ON = TRUE;
```

Comment: I'd recommend re-writing the view to use ANSI joins instead of the long-deprecated implicit joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the source of the "more than one row returned by a subquery" message is that there were duplicate entries within the view.  Once the redundant records were removed from the source table for the view, the error was not encountered.

Answer (score 2):

My guess, without looking too deeply in the code blob you posted, is that you've got a SUB-SELECT statement nested in your code that is trying to select more than one column. With a SUB-SELECT (a SELECT nested within a query), you can only return one column to the outer query as a result.

Comment: Try removing your COALESCE and see if you can return results with SELECT *. If so, that's your issue. Also, did you just exempt ID4 from your query, or do you really not have an ID4? Because you're trying to include it in the View, which could also be an issue (not sure as far as PostGRE).

Comment: ID4 is exempted from the query, I just copied our existing and changed the names.

Comment: Newbie poster here, so if I could have made things clearer (not a quicksand code blob) I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It's a little problematic for me to try removing the coalesce in our environment (I suppose I'll need to find a way).  However, there is not otherwise a problem with the view.  So, I was thinking that the view could be treated as a table.  Does submitting the query lead to the create view getting executed again?  I don't think so, therefore why would a view (just a collection of data) have a problem with selecting all?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Goat CO cleaned up the code and formatted it so it was easier to read. There's a quick primer about formatting code snippets on StackOverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Well, before you remove the COALESCE in your environment, you'll need to test the code with and without the COALESCE. If it works without the COALESCE, then that's your problem. Typically, when you run a query, it executes the whole code snippet - so it will recreate the view every time you run the CREATE VIEW/SELECT query (not when you run the SELECT * FROM MYVIEW, just to be clear).